# Schema JSON - Get selected item from drop down list to populate corresponding data into a text box

Tags: json, textbox, schema, dropdown, selecteditem

Using Schema JSON, I have this drop down list that has data populated into it. Each item in the drop down list has a value. How do I get that value and populate data into a different text box?
For example, let's say the drop down looks like:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

If the user selects "A", how do I find that the user selected "A"? Or even get the selected value 1? And then getting the selected value, a textbox under will say "Correct" or "Incorrect".

Here's what I'm working with:

```
vm.sf.form = [
{
   type: 'fieldset',
   title: 'Some Title',
   items: [
      { key: "Answers", title: "Choose One", type: 'select', onChange: "itemSelected(form.titleMap)", titleMap: getTitleMap()},
      { key: "isCorrect" title: "Your Answer is: ", type: 'string', readonly: true}
    ]
}];
```

The "onChange: "itemSelected(form.titleMap)" calls a function itemSelected, which is where I would like to have the functionality check what is selected. 
The form.titleMap returns "A, B, C, D" but not the actual selected value.

The function for itemSelected looks like this:

```
$scope.itemSelected = function (value) {
   var answer = value;
   if (answer == 'A'){
       //set isCorrect to say "Correct" in the text box...
   }
}
```

The itemSelected function just test code for now.. 
In this function, "value" returns "A, B, C, D" instead of the actual selected value, since I am passing in the titleMap. How do I pass in the selected value? And then how do I change the textbox text to say "Correct" or "Incorrect"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out when I changed the form.titleMap to "this". It helped me map around the form to find the actual value that was selected. When I found the actual selected value, it was easy to do the rest.
I hope this helps others that may have the same issue...